# Wind force field won't affect cloth simulation

Tags: animation, particles, physics, cloth-simulation, force-fields

I am trying to use a wind force field to cause multiple cloth simulation objects to be blown away from their initial location, however when I play the simulation, the simulated cloth objects just fall downwards. I am following a tutorial and have made sure I followed every step, if anyone knows what the issue is and how to fix it, please let me know.

Here is the .blend file:[image]

Comment: It's not just wind-- your cloth isn't doing anything at all, ever.  That's because you've pinned every single vertex, with full (1.0) stiffness.  That means that the cloth modifier will never have any effect whatsoever.

Comment: Oh I see what you're doing.  Your wind is working.  That's why the pieces move in the direction of the wind.  Try moving the wind to a different layer and disabling gravity, see what happens.  Don't forget to clear your cache, moving the forcefield won't clear it for you.